# SQL to sequelize orm query change

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

SQL query is working fine but in node js using suquelize orm query not working.

SQL : Woking Fine

```
select message from tbl_chat where (userId=1 or userId=98) and (receiverId=1 or receiverId=98) and isgroupChat=0;
```

Sequelize ORM : Not working

```
             let result = await Chat.findAll<Chat>({

            where: {
                isgroupChat: 0,
                $and: {
                    $or: [
                        {
                            userId: userId
                        },
                        {
                            userId: userId
                        }
                    ],
                    $or: [
                        {
                            receiverId: receiverId
                        },
                        {
                            receiverId: receiverId
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: What query is the orm generating

Comment: "Not working" _how?_

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why exactly this isn't working. Turn on logging and see what the ORM is producing for a query. But, I'd also try changing the query a little:

```
 {
   where: {
     isGroupChat: 0,
     userId: { $in: [uid1, uid2] },
     receiverId: { $in: [uid1, uid2] }
 }
```